# UIPage ViewController, i want to navigate the other second viewcontroller from non uipage viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, uipageviewcontroller

I need Code for UIpageViewcontroller, which will work like below MVC of Image.

[PageViewController Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXCLf.png)

Edit:

When I Click on next button of "Other ViewController", it will call ViewController 2 of UIPageViewcontroller.
The exact flow is shown in above image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok this is one way to do it

first you need to create a UIPageViewController in the storyboard and set the class to same of this code

in a new swift file copy and paste this

```
class PageVC: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
//make sure the storyboard PageviewControllers class is set to this class or it wont work

lazy var VCArray: [UIViewController] = {
    //here is where your viewController pages go. in storyboard create multiple viewControllers and give them a storyboard ID here is where the storyboard IDs will be put in
    return [self.VCInstance(name: "firstVC"),
            self.VCInstance(name: "secondVC"),
            self.VCInstance(name: "thirdVC")]
}()

private func VCInstance(name: String) -> UIViewController {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.delegate = self
    self.dataSource = self

    if let firstVC = VCArray.first {
        setViewControllers([firstVC], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    for view in self.view.subviews {
        if view is UIScrollView {
            view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        } else if view is UIPageControl {
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }
    }
}

public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = VCArray.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

    guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
        return VCArray.last
    }

    guard VCArray.count > previousIndex else {
        return nil
    }
    return VCArray[previousIndex]
}

public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = VCArray.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1

    guard nextIndex < VCArray.count else {
        return VCArray.first
    }

    guard VCArray.count > nextIndex else {
        return nil
    }
    return VCArray[nextIndex]
}
//this is optional for the page counter at the bottom
public func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return VCArray.count
}
//this is optional for the page counter at the bottom
public func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    guard let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first, let firstViewControllerIndex = VCArray.index(of: firstViewController) else {
        return 0
    }
    return firstViewControllerIndex
}
```

}

Explanation-

the code above is very customizable you can change whether or not you have a page counter at the bottom or how many pages are displayed by using this it turns multiple storyboard viewControllers into a single-paged viewController and because the pages are individual storyboard viewControllers you can put whatever you want on the pages....if you are still confused check out this video on [YouTube](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjV_6CMj7jVAhVj5YMKHVknCEIQtwIIUDAJ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DoX9o-DnMHsE&usg=AFQjCNGpztgqto7Bk0evXnmqFSoDwcczhg)

Comment: Navigation to different view controllers are working good, but i need, when we are in "Other ViewController" it will not in members of UIPageViewController(like ViewController 1, 2, 3), if we click the next button, the view controller will call, pageviewcontroller child(ViewController 2). just check above image in my Question Post.

Comment: what you need to do is make two pageViewControllers using the code above and on the second page of the first pageViewController put a UIButton that navigates to the first page of the second pageViewController if that makes sense